# grep in my specific dictionary

Tags: gvim, quickfix, grep

I often need to make a case-insensitive search of the current word (under cursor) in a dictionary file which has a simple txt format, one entry per line. One possible solution is to record a macro in a register which will make the grep for me and display the matches in the command-line mode, such as

```
:!grep -i word ~/path/to/dictfile.txt
```

where the current word can be substituted by means of ^R^W. This works, but it has some disadvantages.

- The list of matches disappears once I hit Enter. Keeping the results in a window would be useful. The contents of the window should update when I make a new search.
- The list of matches provides no highlighting of the search pattern, which would increase the readability.

I have tried to make a script which would output the matches to another file for viewing. However, I was not able to ensure in the script that exactly one window with the matches stays open and refreshes with a renewed grepping.

Another solution might come via the `:vimgrep` command and displaying the quickfix list via the `:cwindow` command. But there, I get lots of unwanted information (~/path/to/dictfile.txt, |linenumber col colnumber| and no highlighting.

Comment: There’s also `:grep`

Answer (score 1):

You can send the Grep to a split terminal buffer after closing the
buffer from the previous Grep (if any).

```
:sil!bd --color|ter grep --color -i word dictfile
```

- `grep --color` is required to force Grep to use color.
- `bd --color` deletes the buffer whose name matches "--color". This is a good
  keyword because it is unlikely that you will have a filename containing
  "--color". You could also use "grep" as the keyword, but then the command would fail if
  you had a buffer named "meagrepart", for example.
- `sil!` prevents the command from failing if you had no "--color" terminal
  buffer yet.

See also `vert ter` for a vertically split terminal and `tab ter` for
a terminal in a new tab.

Comment: This is a nice solution indeed; I was not aware of the terminal command. I also found in the help I can choose the number of ++rows=<number> to be displayed. Now, I wonder whether it is possible to display the terminal window _below_ the current one, not above as it opens. Also, the terminal window inherits some options from the current window, like foldcolumn=<number> and spell=on, which I would prefer to avoid. Is there a way to change these?

Comment: @user27145 `set splitbelow` in `.vimrc` makes all splits create the new window below the current one. I cannot help you with the second question, though, because I never use spelling and folding.

Comment: Yes, indeed, with `set splitbelow` it works fine. For the options to be set locally, I found the answer from `:h terminal`. It is enough to add to .vimrc the line:

   `autocmd TerminalWinOpen * setlocal fdc=0 |setlocal nospell`

Comment: I have noticed another small issue with the grep: Whereas it works perfectly in plain shell, its output to the vim's term window appears to split long lines into chunks of about 100 characters long. I wonder whether there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: @user27145 I don't get exactly what you mean. In the plain shell, does your lines ever wrap if they are too long to fit the terminal? A picture could help and maybe you would like to open another question.